# Are there any tools for parsing a Visual c++ generated resource script?

Tags: .net, c++, mfc

Are there any tools for parsing a Visual c++ generated resource script?  Is this resource script's format documented any where?  I am looking for something in MFC or .net that could parse some data out of the files for reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any tools for parsing this, but the format is described in [detail at this site](http://sei.pku.edu.cn/~caodg/course/c/reference/win32/resources/script.html).

The resource script files are an ASCII text format, so it should be fairly easy to parse out the information you need.